# Pre-populating Entities into database for testing purposes

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, derby, jpql

I'm developing a Java EE 7 application. For testing purposes, it'd be very beneficial to populate the database with some content. [This tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/persistence-intro005.htm) explains how you can create the database content at or before run time using an SQL file. I'm assuming, within this SQL file, I could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ENTITYNAME(ENTITYATTRIBUTE1, ENTITYATTRIBUTE2, ... ENTITYATTRIBUTEN) value
    ("entityAttribute1", "entityAttribute2, ... "entityAttributeN")
```

If my approach is correct, how would I provide the value of an @ElementCollection, @OneToMany, or just Entity attribute?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pre-populate your database with test data using an sql script, you will have to examine the schema that JPA generates from your `@Entity` classes.

For example if you have 2 `@Entity`s:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @Id int id;
    @ElementCollection Set<String> strings;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy"foo") Set<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @Id int id;
    @ManyToOne
    Foo foo;
}
```

You are going to have to check for yourself, but the generated schema might look somethings like this.

```sql
create table Foo {
     id int primary key
}

create table Foo_strings {
     Foo_id int references Foo (id),
     strings varchar,
}

create table Bar {
    id int primary key,
    Foo_id references Foo(id)
}
```

So if you wanted to create some test data in sql, you could create a `setup_test_data.sql` like:

```sql
insert into Foo values (1);

insert into Foo_strings values (1, "string 1");
insert into Foo_strings values (1, "string 2");

insert into Bar values (1, 1);
insert into Bar values (2, 1);
```

This would be the same as a `Foo` with 2 `String`s in the strings `@ElementCollection` and 2 `Bar`s in the bars `@OneToMany` relation.